# Write dynamic INNER JOIN in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I want to write a dynamic function for INNER JOIN in pdo. I want send table name and condition to function and create dynamic query in function.

```
SELECT *  
FROM :tbl 
INNER JOIN :tbl2 ON :tbl1.id = :tbl2.id 
WHERE :tbl2.id  = :value;
```

I want to passed tbl, tbl2, tbl.id, tbl2.id, and WHERE condition to function and create dynamic query and biindParam with PDO then execute query.

How can I write this function?

Comment: i need a dynamic function for INNER JOIN. id don`t know how to implement with PDO and bindParam. can you give me an example?

Comment: i know how to use prepare and bindParam.i want to have `function($tbl , $where)` and when i call it **INNER JOIN** 2 table and fetch data.

Comment: what's the point in having such a function?

Comment: i need to this function to complete database model in my own MVC framework.

Comment: it's not an answer. what particular reason to have such a function?

Comment: If you're trying to build a dynamic query *builder*, one, I suggest not doing so (since it would impact your ability to find bugs), and two, what you want to do with PDO is not possible (as @Col. Shrapnel points out). You would have to build the query up with the different tables in PHP. The only part that I believe you could do in PDO is the `:value` part.

Comment: when i need to join two table how can i do?

Comment: just join it. `SELECT * FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id 
WHERE tbl2.id  = :value;`

Comment: If you're bound and determine to do it, you'll have to use PHP for the table names, ie, `INNER JOIN $tbl2 ON $tbl1.id = $tbl2.id ` and then PDO for the `:value` on execute.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel  And Jared Farrish thanks for reply

Comment: @Jared so, you're spoiled all security benefits of PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't bind identifiers. 
So, table and field names  should be added into query directly.

However, if you need such a dynamic join, it's most likely because your database setup is wrong.
And you'd better normalize it. So, you will have more reliable database yet will be no need in such dynamical joins